# Display most recent date + unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL script (using SQL Server 2008):

```
SELECT distinct 
    ServiceIdentifier as ReceivedFrom, EventDate
FROM 
    [dbo].AttendanceEvent                                                  
WHERE 
    ServiceIdentifier in (5001, 5003, 5004)
```

that displays the `date` (column: `EventDate`) and organisation code (column: `ServiceIdentifier`) for each row in my table (name: `AttendanceEvent`).

I use the `where serviceidentifier in (x,y,z)` clause to enter in specific organisations I want to look at.

This script is pretty handy, except that it pulls every individual record which is too much and times out my SQL.

I want to refine the script to only pull the most recent date for each organisation.

Giving me 1 line per `serviceidentifier`.

The date format that `EventDate` is in is; 2014-08-23 19:31:44.163 if that impacts anything.

Any help and advice hugely appreciated!

E.H

P.S I looked through some of the other questions but couldn't really tell if mine was a duplicate, if you think it is, please let me know and I'll look there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `group by`:

```
SELECT ServiceIdentifier as ReceivedFrom, max(EventDate) as EventDate
FROM [dbo].AttendanceEvent                                                  
where ServiceIdentifier in (5001, 5003, 5004)
group by ServiceIdentifier;
```